# Can EF 6 Data Annotations be different for POST than PUT or GET?

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

We are building a RESTful web service where there are sometimes different required fields for a POST than a PUT.  For example, a field like CustomerSinceDate is allowed to be set on an insert, but not on an update.  Is there is a way to set that up with Data Annotations?

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework does not (and should not) know anything about your web service. It deals only with what rules exist in the persistence layer.

What you are looking for is validation.

So in your REST service, you should check whether CustomerSinceData has been changed, and the entity is being updated. If so, you should throw an Exception with an appropriate message to the consumer.

Here is an article on writing your own DataAnnotations, if you prefer using those:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164#attributes

Otherwise, take a look at this article on how to write your own custom validation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx
(in particular, the section on IValidatableObject).

Your rule could be formulated as (pseudo code)

```
//if object exists in db AND CustomerSinceData has changed
```

DataAnnotations will get you a long way, but can be tedious to write if you are writing business logic that will never be reused anywhere else.

Comment: The question is more about documentation. Let me try to clarify. Just getting into this, so not sure I'm using the right terms. Data Annotations generate documentation for consumers of the web services, but it can be misleading.  If I mark a field [Required], that shows up whether you're looking at the documentation for GET, PUT, or POST. Some fields that are applicable on a POST (like CustomerSinceDate) cannot be set in a PUT, etc. I know how to set up validation, but wondered if I can show/hide parameters in the documentation or display different comments depending on the function. Possible?